# What are the proper GitHub settings to prevent people from committing to the master branch?

Tags: github, permissions, access-control

I want to set up a proper workflow on GitHub where junior engineers submit pull request for code review and only the lead engineer can commit to the master branch.

I'm looking for input from professionals that work in a commercial software environment. I've found the page that does the permissions easy enough. There are several options. Restrict who can push to matching branches of course. Should I check others as well?

Comment: In the repository, Settings > Branches > Branch protection rules. Typing your question title into Google finds the doc on this: https://www.google.com/search?q=github+people+from+committing+to+the+master+branch

Comment: Yeah that's what I found too but it seemed too simplistic. I wanted to come here to get input from professionals that do this stuff everyday in a commercial software environment.

Comment: Could you clarify what "too simplistic" means? It does exactly what you say you want.

Comment: Yup. Question updated.

Comment: Which restrictions to put in place is up to you. If you have other branches you want to protect, by all means protect them. It remains unclear to me what more you're looking for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other approach, beside the branch permission within *one* repo, is the gate repo:

- you are setting up a public repo where developers can commit (on master or topic branches)
- you are using a private, or repo within an organisation, from which you can *pull*

That way, you or your organisation team control the contribution you chose to include in the master of that main repository.